# how can I find default attributes for JTextPane document?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I'm working with a JTextPane.

```
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
String content = "I'm a line of text that will be displayed in the JTextPane";
StyledDocument doc = pane.getStyledDocument();
SimpleAttributeSet aSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
```

If I add this `aSet` to the textpane's document like this:

```
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, content.length(), aSet, false);
```

Nothing visible happens. No big surprise since I haven't set any custom attributes for `aSet`. However, if I allow `aSet` to replace the current ParagraphAttributes of `doc` like this:

```
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, content.length(), aSet, true);
```

A lot of things happen. How can I get information on those default values of the JTextPane document? Particularly my problems is that when I'm defining a custom Font for `aSet` and set it to replace the current attributes, the font is displayed as if it was bold. `StyleConstants.setBold(aSet, false);` doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have looked at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/swing/text/DefaultStyledDocument.java#DefaultStyledDocument.setParagraphAttributes%28int%2Cint%2Cjavax.swing.text.AttributeSet%2Cboolean%29) to see what data structures are holding the information that you want. This is a modification of that code that prints the attributes for each paragraph.

```
int offset, length; //The value of the first 2 parameters in the setParagraphAttributes() call

Element section = doc.getDefaultRootElement();
int index0 = section.getElementIndex(offset);
int index1 = section.getElementIndex(offset + ((length > 0) ? length - 1 : 0));
for (int i = index0; i <= index1; i++)
{
    Element paragraph = section.getElement(i);
    AttributeSet attributeSet = paragraph.getAttributes();
    Enumeration keys = attributeSet.getAttributeNames();
    while (keys.hasMoreElements())
    {
        Object key = keys.nextElement();
        Object attribute = attributeSet.getAttribute(key);
        //System.out.println("key = " + key); //For other AttributeSet classes this line is useful because it shows the actual parameter, like "Bold"
        System.out.println(attribute.getClass());
        System.out.println(attribute);
    }
}
```

The output for a simple textPane with some text added through the `setText()` method gives:

```
class javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle
NamedStyle:default {foreground=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],size=12,italic=false,name=default,bold=false,FONT_ATTRIBUTE_KEY=javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=Dialog,name=Dialog,style=plain,size=12],family=Dialog,}
```

About your particular problem, looking at a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567028/coloring-texts-in-java) I have been able to set the text of a paragraph to bold with:

```
StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
AttributeSet aSet = sc.addAttribute(aSet,  StyleConstants.Bold,  true);
```

In this case the class of `aSet` is `javax.swing.text.StyleContext$SmallAttributeSet` which is not mutable (does not implement `MutableAttributeSet`). For your case something along the lines:

```
aSet.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Bold, true);
```

should work.

Comment: to set attributes of aSet I use `StyleConstants.setFontFamily(aSet, "Times New Roman");` and that works perfectly fine :). Your answer shows me that what I thought was bold text is the color attribute (foreground) resetting from default `[r=51, g=51, b=51]` to `[r=0, g=0, b=0]`. So thank you very much, very helpful!

Comment: @user2651804 Glad I could help! Note that the `StyleConstants.setXXX(aMutableSet, value)` methods exist for comodity, they just call `aMutableSet.addAttribute(StyleConstants.XXX, value)`. [Example](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/text/StyleConstants.java#StyleConstants.setFontFamily%28javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet%2Cjava.lang.String%29).

Comment: These kinds of things, designed to make our lives easier, ends up complicating the life of a new java programmer, I guess...